Openresty throwing error 413: Request Entity Too Large
I am using ingress-nginx helmchart(version: 4.10.1) on kubernetes cluster(v1.29) Deployed in OKE. When I try to perform one migration activity I am getting error thrown as below:
413 Request Entity Too Large
openresty
The file size I am trying to migrate is around 10MB.
Any suggestions if any other parameter that I need to change to make it working.
I added the below parameter in custom-values.yaml while deploying the helm chart but still it is not permitting.
controller:
config:
proxy-body-size: "100M"

I added the below parameter in custom-values.yaml while deploying the helm chart but still it is not permitting.
controller:
config:
proxy-body-size: "100M"


413 Request Entity Too Large

413 Request Entity Too Large
openresty


client_max_body_size: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

@grug.0 thanks for checking but the proxy-body-size parameter changes the client_max_body_size  in the nginx.conf file which I have already verified, the error point towards the openresty config, is there any parameter that modifies the value for openresty?

The problem resided in one of the pods of the which was having configuration as below:
containers:

env:

name: CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE
value: 8m
Due to this, even the value was increased in ingress configuration, I was not able to upload the file.
I updated the configuration to 20 MB and the file was successfully uploaded.
containers:


env:

name: CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE
value: 20m



If anyone observes similar issue which is throwing "413: Request entity too large error" with the tag Openresty, I will suggest to review other configurations apart from NGINX controller as well like pods, any other proxy present.
